# Массив изображений в vb6

Tags: массивы, vb6

У меня есть 1 Image на форме. Хотелось бы из него получить массив Image.

Когда гуглил, то нашёл что нужно использовать Load. Например:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Load Image1(i)
    Image1(i).Visible = True
Next i
```

Но этот способ не работает. Выбивает ошибку: Type Mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.

Для создания такого массива необходимо у вашего Image на форме в свойствах задать параметр Index. К примеру 1. После этого вы можете добавлять в этот массив новые элементы тем способом, который указан выше.